# SQL Server Add X rows to results to always equal a 5 row output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have code which returns the last 5 results for any given ID (including the ID given). What i want is to return extra rows with the word `none` and `00` respectively if there aren't previous values to equal 5.

So if the code returns 3 results generate 2 extra rows, if the code returns 4 results generate 1 extra row.

Current Code: (`aaa.FS01 = '12345'`) is just an example of an ID

```
SELECT aaa.FS01,
CAST(COUNT(distinct bbb.MG) AS FLOAT)/ convert(varchar(10), DATEDIFF(second ,MIN(TP), MAX(TP))/3600.0) TPDIFF,
22 TAG
FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableB bbb ON bbb.tpl = aaa.FS01 OR bbb.fpl = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableC ccc ON ccc.id = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableD ddd ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey
WHERE aaa.FS01 IN (
SELECT TOP 5 ccc.id 
FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableC ccc ON ccc.id = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableD v ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey
WHERE ddd.name = (SELECT ddd.name FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableD v ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey WHERE aaa.FS01 = '12345')
ORDER BY ccc.ata DESC) 
GROUP BY aaa.FS01, ccc.ata
ORDER BY ccc.ata DESC
```

Current Output (For an `FS01` that only returns 3 values):

```
FS01    TPDIFF   TAG
12345   30       22
22222   50       22
45122   90       22
```

Expected Output (For an `FS01` that only returns 3 values):

```
FS01    TPDIFF   TAG
12345   30       22
22222   50       22
45122   90       22
none    00       22
none    00       22
```

Current Output (For an `FS01` that only returns 1 value):

```
FS01    TPDIFF   TAG
74133   30       22
```

Expected Output (For an `FS01` that only returns 1 value):

```
FS01    TPDIFF   TAG
74133   80       22
none    00       22
none    00       22
none    00       22
none    00       22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare a table variable like this. Then use a while to append empty rows.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(FS01 text, TPDIFF text, TAG Text);
INSERT INTO @tbl (FS01, TPDIFF, TAG) 

--your select statement (copied)
SELECT aaa.FS01,
CAST(COUNT(distinct bbb.MG) AS FLOAT)/ convert(varchar(10), DATEDIFF(second ,MIN(TP), MAX(TP))/3600.0) TPDIFF,
22 TAG
FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableB bbb ON bbb.tpl = aaa.FS01 OR bbb.fpl = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableC ccc ON ccc.id = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableD ddd ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey
WHERE aaa.FS01 IN (
SELECT TOP 5 ccc.id 
FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableC ccc ON ccc.id = aaa.FS01
INNER JOIN TableD v ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey
WHERE ddd.name = (SELECT ddd.name FROM TableA aaa
INNER JOIN TableD v ON aaa.VG = ddd.gkey WHERE aaa.FS01 = '12345')
ORDER BY ccc.ata DESC) 
GROUP BY aaa.FS01, ccc.ata
ORDER BY ccc.ata DESC


declare @cnt as int;
SELECT @cnt = count(*) from @tbl

while @cnt < 5
    BEGIN
        insert into @tbl (FS01, TPDIFF, TAG) VALUES('none', '00', '22');
        select @cnt = @cnt+1;
    end

select top 5 * from @tbl;
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Operand type clash: float is incompatible with text` error and its highlighting the line `INSERT INTO @tbl (FS01, TPDIFF, TAG) `

Comment: In the first line change the types from text to match the types returned from your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single query:

```
with t as (<your query here>),
     nones as (
      select 'none' as FS01, '00' as TPDIFF, '22' as TAG
      from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5))
     )
select top (5) tn.FS01, tn.TPDIFF, tn.TAG
from ((select t.* from t) union all
      nones
     ) tn
order by (case when FS01 = 'none' then 1 else 2 end) as asc;
```